# Goal tracking of receipt page counts each page refresh

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-analytics

In the Goal section in Google Analytics you can provide an URL such as:  /thankyou.html which a customer will only see once before being redirected. They can't go back to the thankyou page again.

However, in our store website, once a customer checks out, they are redirected automatically to the receipt page, such as:

http://www.domain.com/store/receipt/?ouid=23424asasdfbb34345

The end is a random number, you can't enter it into the goal. The best is to enter:

/store/receipt/

Viewing that page counts as a purchase goal, and they can revisit this page over and over, each time counting as a checkout.

Is there any way to prevent their visits getting counted more than once while make the goal count?

The store website software does have a code on the receipt page which enable functions to fire only once:

```
//fire only the first time a page is viewed
if(is_object($order) && $order->viewed == 0)
{
//code here
}
```

Would it help if I manually placed the analytic code inside this code block?
The problem with doing that is that it is already in my header automatically via the Google Analytic WordPress plugin from Yoast.

Comment: As per documentation (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2976313?hl=en halfway down the page) goals are only tracked once per session in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy solution would be for you put in a virtual pageview in the code that you pasted. So... it would fire a virtual pageviews only one-time, once a users reaches the page.

If you are using the OLD google analytics tracking block, will need to add the below code:

```
//fire only the first time a page is viewed
if(is_object($order) && $order->viewed == 0)
{
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/someone_purchased']);
}
```

If you are using the NEW google analytics tracking block, will need to add the below code:

```
//fire only the first time a page is viewed
if(is_object($order) && $order->viewed == 0)
{
ga('send', 'pageview', '/someone_purchased');
}
```

Once you add the above code, you will start seeing a page called "someone_purchased" in your google analytics. You then add that page as a goal and voila!

Hope this helps!